H2 alias function for stored procedure that returns multiple ResultSets?
I am currently using H2 alias functions to mimic stored procedure calls.  This is working fine with stored procedures that return a single resultset, but now I need to create an alias function for a stored procedure that returns two resultsets, and I am struggling to understand how you do this with a H2 alias finction.
I have tried to return List and SimpleResultSet[] from the alias method, but these just cause an error in the Jdbc layer.
The alias method is below.  As you can see it needs to return the two result set objects and their associated metadata.
public static ResultSet someMethodName(final Connection connection) throws SQLException {

  //Metadata for RS1
  final SimpleResultSet resultSet1 = new SimpleResultSet();
  resultSet1.addColumn("field_1", Types.VARCHAR, 10, 0);
  resultSet1.addColumn("field_2", Types.VARCHAR, 10, 0);

  //Metadata for rs2
  final SimpleResultSet resultSet2 = new SimpleResultSet();
  resultSet1.addColumn("field_1", Types.INTEGER, 10, 0);
  resultSet1.addColumn("field_2", Types.INTEGER, 10, 0);

  if (connection.getMetaData().getURL().equals("jdbc:columnlist:connection")) {
    //How do you return the two ResultSet instances?
  }

   //How do you return the two ResultSet instances?
}

The code for executing the SP and processing the result set data, which works fine when invoking the actual SP in sybase is as follows.
final SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]{
        new SqlReturnResultSet("result_1", (rs) -> {
          listA.add(ObjectA.builder()
              .field1(rs.getString("field_1"))
              .field2(rs.getString("field_2"))
              .build());
        }),
        new SqlReturnResultSet("result_2", (rs) -> {
          listB.add(ObjectB.builder()
              .field1((Integer) rs.getObject("field_1"))
              .field2((Integer) rs.getObject("field_2"))
              .build());
        }),
    };

final List<ObjectA> listA = new ArrayList<>();
final List<ObjectB> listB = new ArrayList<>();

return new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
    .withSchemaName("dbo")
    .withProcedureName(spName)
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
    .declareParameters(parameters)
    .execute(Arrays.stream(parameters)
        .filter(SqlParameterValue.class::isInstance)
        .map(SqlParameterValue.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(SqlParameterValue::getName, SqlParameterValue::getValue)));


"I have tried ....  but these just cause an error"  Please make your question a [mre], including all details to make it useful for future readers.

The question look sooo much better with all these details available
